# .Net Maui Button Template

Tags: maui

Is it possible to template a Button in .Net Maui such as:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I have searched but without success. Actually I want different Corner Radius for my button

Comment: I think it's better use a [Visual states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: Did you consider creating a custom control where you put your button inside a `Border` control? That would allow you to set corner radius individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you want to set each corner of the button. And as ewerspej suggested, you could wrap it in the Border and set the Border corner. Here is the example also in Visual State:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" >
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="AliceBlue"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="myBorder" Property="Border.StrokeShape">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="0,0,0,40" />  
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>

.......


<Border x:Name="myBorder">
    
    <Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Text="Click me"
            CornerRadius="0"
    />
</Border>
```

For more info, you could refer to [Button visual states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/button?view=net-maui-7.0#button-visual-states) and [Visual states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states?view=net-maui-7.0).

Comment: Not sure if Visual State would work. in .Net Maui you can apply CornerRadius to a button but can only set like this:
<Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="15"/> 
but not like this: 
<Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,0,15"/>. 
You can only set CornerRadius that applies to all four sides but not individually, which is what I want

Comment: You could wrap the button in a Border, which supports setting individual radii for corners.

Comment: @ewerspej  thanks for your suggestion. wrap the button in a Border is a good idea.

Comment: @user10403352 Hi, I update my answer using ewerspej suggestion. But also use visual states.

Comment: The above works though I used:
'<Border  StrokeThickness="0" >
                <Border.StrokeShape>
                    <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="0,0,0,13"/>
               </Border.StrokeShape>
               <Button/>
            </Border>'